# IC50 with curve fit line and value of IC50 appear on the graph using pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

Please help me to make IC50 graph with data as follow

```
S(mM)   Activity (%) 
0.00080 99 %
0.00800 91 %
0.08000 89 %
0.40000 89 %
0.80000 79 %
1.60000 61 %
4.00000 39 %
8.00000 25 %
80.00000    4 %
```

and also IC50 value appear at 50% inhibition on the graph with curve fit line like EC50.

I give sample (modefied by me) from web site http://bpsbioscience.com/poly-adp-ribose-polymerase/inhibitors/xav-939-27100 
[image]

Comment: Most of us are not familiar with IC50 plots: could you link to an example?

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: sorry, actually this question is related with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend  but i really dont know  how to play with this latex. I am sorry, but I assure you this IC50 is generally used by biochemist. So this is useful question to help many people related with drug/enzymatic studies.

Comment: Instead of linking to the question why don't you put a MWE such that we can directly copy/paste and see if we can come up something? As @AndrewUzzell commented, it is very likely that this question will be closed as too localized because it is a *do-it-for-me* question.

Comment: Sorry for my bad manner. Please dont close it if you know the answer, it will help thousands of "totally beginner"  like me who need this for their research.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend/29678#29678 for an automatic way to do the fit using gnuplot within LaTeX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments to @Habi's answer, `pgfplots` cannot perform a non-linear regression of your data. That's why you have to rely on an external tool (I used a quick `fit` routine in `gnuplot`).

Once you obtained the fitted parameter(s), you can use `pgfplots` to draw a plot of the fitted curve/function, like so:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27618/828
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[%
        xlabel={S / \si{\milli\Molar}},%
        ylabel={\% Activity},%
        legend pos=south west,%
        legend style={cells={anchor=west}}%
        ]
    \addplot [blue,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {
            ( 0.00080, 99)
            ( 0.00800, 91)
            ( 0.08000, 89)
            ( 0.40000, 89)
            ( 0.80000, 79)
            ( 1.60000, 61)
            ( 4.00000, 39)
            ( 8.00000, 25)
            (80.00000, 4)
            };
    \addlegendentry{data};
    % add plot of fitted curve with IC50=2.62645 mM (obtained via gnuplot)
    % %Activity = max * S / (IC50 + S) + min
    \addplot[red,smooth,domain=1e-3:100] { 100 * 2.63645 / (2.63645 + x) };
    \addlegendentry{sigmoidal fit}
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, i have another request if you dont mind, 1) could you calculate it by calling gnuplot in latex? and 2) if you have idea, how to put value of IC50 as i show in sample IC50 graph above?

Comment: @limpato: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend/29678#29678 for one way of doing that.

Comment: @limpato ad 1) While you can do that (see @Jake's comment), I prefer not to. In particular, because I like to keep the data evaluation and the reporting separate. ad 2) You can draw nodes within the plot's coordinate system using the `axis cs` key for coordinates.

Comment: @Jake and hakaze Thank you,  I have tried to create the graph according your suggestion in that page, I found the blue line shift to left side after print to pdf. my computer, I use Japanese Windows XP SP3, Miktex 2.9, gnuplot 4.6, TexStudio 2.4. Do you know what is wrong? Please check https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B851Prvsye7yRG1uTXZ3SnhPSEE/edit?pli=1

Comment: @limpato Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that's not what you want, is it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27618/828
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[%
        xlabel={S [\si{\milli\Molar}]},%
        ylabel=Activity%
        ]
    \addplot [smooth,blue,mark=*] coordinates {
            ( 0.00080, 99)
            ( 0.00800, 91)
            ( 0.08000, 89)
            ( 0.40000, 89)
            ( 0.80000, 79)
            ( 1.60000, 61)
            ( 4.00000, 39)
            ( 8.00000, 25)
            (80.00000, 4)
            };
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which ends up to look like this: [image: image from code above]

**update**: code changed to reflect the example posted.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I need curve fit line sigmoid which called from gnuplot and also IC50 is written in the graph as sample i send.

Comment: @limpato please the `pgfplots` manual section 4.2.5 "Computing Coordinates with Mathematical Expressions (gnuplot)". AFAIK `pgfplots` can only perform a linear regression on its own. So you will have to perform the sigmoidal fit externally.

Comment: As @hakaze said, you cannot calculate the curve fit directly with TikZ, you need to calculate it externally and then bring it back into the plot. You might be able to work with MATLAB or python, which both can export to TikZ with either https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz or https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz