# Units, units in fractions

Tags: fractions, units

I'm new to latex and trying to figure out the notation.

I'm trying to type out conversions, like (for example) `5 lbf * (4.4482 N / 1 lbf)= etc`  etc.

I'm not sure how to make the units show as units, or, at least, not as italics. I've seen how you can use `\si{N}`, but `lbf` isn't an `SI` unit, and I don't know how to combine `\si` with `\frac`.

Comment: Hi, welcome. `siunitx` lets you declare new units, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/expressing-capital-m-for-molar-in-siunitx-package/27618#27618 Then if you've defined an `\lbf` unit, you can do e.g. `\SI{4.4482}{\newton\per\lbf}`.  Note capital `\SI` which is for a number with a unit.

Comment: The `siunitx` package allows  you to define your own units and typesets them in a consistent way.

Answer (score 2):

Units are placed in upright font, and the spacing between a number and its unit is smaller than the usual spacing between words.  Furthermore, the number and its unit should not be broken up over two lines of text.

This is a good article that discusses typesetting mathematics for science:
http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf

The following macro can be placed in the preamble to help with units. In works in and out of mathmode.

```
\providecommand*{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\,#1}}}
```

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\providecommand*{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\,#1}}}

\begin{document}
You can type units in manually, $1\,\mathrm{lbf} = 4.4482\,\mathrm{N}$

Or you can use the macro defined above:
\begin{equation*}
    5.00\unit{lbf} \left(\frac{4.4482\unit{N} }{ 1\unit{lbf}}\right) = 22.2\unit{N}
\end{equation*}

These give the same result:

22.2\unit{N}

22.2\,N

$22.2\,\mathrm{N}$

Since mathmode gets rid of whitespace, this doesn't look right:

$1\,\mathrm{N} = 1\,\mathrm{kg m/s^2}$

This looks right:

$1\,\mathrm{N} = 1\,\mathrm{kg\,m/s^2}$

\end{document}
```

[image]